# How to get basic jQuery working

Tags: jquery

I've done all the tutorials at Codecademy so I thought I was all ready to rock with jQuery. Then I went to write my own code... and nothing happened.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<div id="tester">
Hello World
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tester').click(function() {
        $('tester').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you think should have happened, that didn't?

Comment: @mustaccio Maybe you should read the code before commenting. His slip up is obvious

Comment: @Jesse -- so what did _you_ think should have happened, that didn't? And why?

Comment: @mustaccio, Your comment has only 2 possible meanings. 1. You ignored the code and posted your message to be rude. 2. You missed the coding mistake and are trying to get more information. In either scenario, ""Maybe you should read the code before commenting. His slip up is obvious""

Comment: @Jesse -- I'm afraid you missed some other possible meanings of my comment, but that's OK, since you posted your message to be rude, that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont forget the hashtag/pound sign(#) when you are referencing an id.

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#tester').click(function() {
         $('#tester').fadeOut('slow');
         });
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong. Change `$('tester')` to `$('#tester')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tester').click(function() {
        $('#tester').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tester">
Hello World
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `#` for ID's and `.` for classes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tester').click(function() {
        $('#tester').fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $(".myclass").click(function(){
       alert("My class clicked");
    });

});
</script>
```